# Facebook og:title error

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

This is my page: http://www.tutoriallapp.com/viewtutorial?title=How+to+Make+Pizza&tut_id=934&cat_id=1

I am setting the facebook open graph title using this:

```
$tut_title = $_GET['title'];
<meta name="og:title" content="<? echo $tut_title; ?>" />
```

However, facebook debug tool keeps telling me:

> Inferred Property:    The `og:title` property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

When I hard code the title, it works ... but when I use `$_GET`, it does not work. Just do not get it. Any help, please and thank you.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutoriallapp.com%2Fviewtutorial%3Ftitle%3DHow%2Bto%2BMake%2BPizza%26tut_id%3D934%26cat_id%3D1

Answer (score 3):

I see this.

```
<meta name="og:title" content="How+to+Make+Pizza" />
<meta name="og:description" content="How+to+Make+Pizza" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_us" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="672940935"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.tutoriallapp.com/viewtutorial?title=How+to+Make+Pizza&tut_id=934&cat_id=1"/>
```

I wonder if it would be better to try without the + characters in the string value.